# Formatting vaadin table values?

Tags: java, containers, vaadin, vaadin7

Problem is solved. Using JPAContainer not need use `addContainerProperty()`. I comment the line and bingo, now works with values formated.

Now works !

```
final Table table = new Table("Formatted Table") {
    @Override
    protected String formatPropertyValue(Object rowId,
            Object colId, Property property) {
        // Format by property type
        if (property.getType() == Date.class) {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            return df.format((Date)property.getValue());
        }

        return super.formatPropertyValue(rowId, colId, property);
    }
};

// not need with jpacontainer
//table.addContainerProperty("Time", Date.class, null);
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 4):

In Vaadin 7 you can add a Converter to your component. There's no need to override / extend the Table class.

```
table.setConverter(PROPERTY, new StringToDateConverter());
```

You can even change the DateFormat by simply overriding StringToDateConverters `public DateFormat getFormat(Locale locale)` method.

More information [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Formatting+data+in+Table) and [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.properties.html).